# A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server Error C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sqlbulkcopy

I tried to read information from excel file and save it in SQL .

When I run the code local it works perfect but the exception thrown only in the **test** environment.

The error is:

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)

My code looks like this:

```
public bool ExtractExcelToDB(int activityId, string tableName, string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        var path = GetPath(activityId);
        path = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

        using (FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream))
            {
                DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
                DataTable dt = result.Tables["sheet"];
                DataTable newDt = dt.Select().Skip(1).Take(dt.Rows.Count).CopyToDataTable();

                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(GetConnectionString()))
                {
                    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                    sqlBulk.WriteToServer(newDt);
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I write the exception to DB and the code failed in this row:

```
sqlBulk.WriteToServer(newDt);
```

My connection string in the server looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="xxx" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxx;initial catalog=xxx;persist security info=True;user id=xxx;password=xxx;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I tried almost every solution I saw without success.

**EDIT**

> I can save file with 50 rows but not with 2000.. (Problem only in test
>   environment not in local)

Comment: What does your connection string look like? Is your server set  up to received remote connection?

Comment: Can you access the `data source` as specified  using SSMS or similar to check that the connection actually works.

Comment: I select a lot of data from sql in my site and all works good(I mean test and local both)  BTW I using Entity franework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days I founded this work for me (Also using @marc_s answer)

I use transaction and "save" each time only 10 rows

Here is my code:

```
public bool ExtractExcelToDB(int activityId, string tableName, string fileName) {
  using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionStringBulk())) {
    SqlTransaction tran = null;
    try {
      connection.Open();
      tran = connection.BeginTransaction();

      var path = GetPath(activityId);
      path = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
      using(FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
        using(IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream)) {
          DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
          DataTable dt = result.Tables["sheet"];
          DataTable newDt = dt.Select().Skip(1).Take(dt.Rows.Count).CopyToDataTable();
          using(SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, tran)) {
            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = tableName;

            var bacth = newDt.Rows.Count / 10;
            for (int i = 0; i <= bacth; i++) {
              var rows = newDt.Select().Skip(i * 10).Take(10).ToArray();
              sqlBulk.WriteToServer(rows);
            }
          }

          tran.Commit();

        }
        return true;
      }


    } catch (Exception ex) {


      db.ExceptionErrors.Add(new ExceptionError {
        Value = ex.Message,
          Date = DateTime.Now
      });
      db.SaveChanges();

      if (tran != null) {
        tran.Rollback();
      }

      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current connection string is a **Entity Framework** connection string - using the rather old, no longer really supported database-first approach with an `.edmx` database model.

For the `SqlBulkCopy`, you need a *clean*, raw ADO.NET connection string - try something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BulkCopy" 
         connectionString="data source=xxx;initial catalog=xxx;persist security info=True;user id=xxx;password=xxx;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Use this connection string for your `SqlBulkCopy` (adapt your `GetConnectionString` method to return this "pure" ADO.NET connection string for the bulk copy component),

Comment: I will try it But you know why it happened only in test and not in local?

Comment: this name is only example or necessary `name="BulkCopy" `?

Comment: The name can be anything - just not "xxx" - it has to be **unique** in your config file

Comment: and how I select this specific name and not the other?

Comment: `string bulkCopyConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BulkCopy"].ConnectionString;` (replace "`BulkCopy" with whatever name you've chosen for your bulk copy connection stirng

Comment: I tried locally and it works perfect the issue is test version

Comment: Well, then there must be something fundamentally different between your local and test environments - but from what you've posted so far, there's no way we can spot that for you and help you ....

Comment: **EDIT** :

I can save file with 50 rows but not with 2000.. (Problem only in test environment not in local)

Answer (score -1):

You should see this page from msdn  ...

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/89d4a844-180a-40df-ba48-b3dade9b310c/error-a-transportlevel-error-has-occurred-when-receiving-results-from-the-server-provider?forum=adodotnetentityframework